# What species is this larva?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I'm trying to identify the species of what I think may be some kind of Lappet Moth larva? (wild guess based on some internet sleuthing)  But the markings don't really match nicely with any photos I can find.

It's light grey/blue-ish, with sparse tufts.  Horn-like hairs at the head and not much going on at the tail.  It's about 75 mm long (not quite 3 inches).

It was found in a bag of grass clippings after mowing the lawn.  Geographic location is the Bruce Peninsula in Ontario, Canada.  Did not find any others like it on the property.  It's unfamiliar to me (first time I've seen one like it).

Can anyone more positively identify?

[image]

Comment: Might be American Lappet Moth (Phyllodesma americana), check the trees above for more. If convenient, stretch it out a little, or make it angry to see possible orange bands.